# Preset tooltips

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I take some text the user inputs. Process the text. I write the text using Text() with an AnnotatedString, setting some words to green. That works fine.

I want to add a tooltip (maybe wrong word) that is different for each green word. The user presses on the green word to see the tooltip.

I have tried looking through the docs and seem to not find something matching.

An analogy is imagine a block of text with technical terms written in green. User presses on the green technical term to see an explanation popup. There can be multiple different technical terms in the block of text, each needing a different explanation popup.

PlainTooltipBox and RichTooltipBox seem to apply to a whole UI element and not a section of it.

ClickableText seems close but looks messy. The text that is processed, can change (user input changes). Seems like I would need a list/array with tables of offsets, lengths and popup text. Use the onClick callback, look into the list and see if the passed in offset, see if there is a word in a suitable range, show text? (not sure how to do that)

Is there not a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried, skydoves/balloon ?

[link for github repo](https://github.com/skydoves/Balloon)

for this you dont need to wrap up the whole UI,
just add on top of a element(Text compose) you want

> the solution may seems long and unnecessary but, if you wrap your texts inside of a composable , it's worth trying

**example**

```
@Composable
fun exampleBalloon(
  val text = "some long text user cant be seen whole "
 ){



// customize the layer
val balloon = Balloon.Builder(context)
    .setLayout(R.layout.layout_custom_profile)
    .setArrowSize(10)
    .setArrowOrientation(ArrowOrientation.TOP)
    .setArrowPosition(0.5f)
    .setWidthRatio(0.55f)
    .setHeight(250)
    .setCornerRadius(4f)
    .setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.black))
    .setBalloonAnimation(BalloonAnimation.CIRCULAR)
    .setLifecycleOwner(lifecycleOwner)
    .build()

    Balloon(
    builder = balloon,
    balloonContent = {
                     //content inside of the overlay layer
                     Text(text = text)
    },
    content =  { balloonWindow ->
        Text(text = text,
      modifier = Modifier.width(60.dp)
      //the clickable invoke the new layer
               .clickable{balloonWindow.showAlignTop()}
    , maxLines = 1, overflow = 
   TextOverflow.Ellipsis)
    })

    }
```